# How do I finish this R function for movie scraping?

Tags: r, web-scraping, video

I'm writing an R function. I would like it to be able to take a list of movies, download info about them, and then throw it into a data frame.
So far,

```
rottenrate <- function(movie){
  link <- paste("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=", movie, "&y=&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true", sep = "")
  jsonData <- fromJSON(link)
  return(jsonData)
}
```

This will return info for one movie and won't convert to a data.frame.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what columns do you expect in your data frame? Can you provide samples movie ids and show the desired output for that input?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
# First, vectorize function
rottenrate <- function(movie){
  require(RJSONIO)
  link <- paste("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=", movie, "&y=&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true", sep = "")
  jsonData <- fromJSON(link)
  return(jsonData)
}
vrottenrate <- Vectorize(rottenrate, "movie", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# Now, query and combine
movies <- c("inception", "toy story")
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vrottenrate(movies), function(x) as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
dplyr::glimpse(df)
# Observations: 2
# Variables:
# $ Title             (chr) "Inception", "Toy Story"
# $ Year              (chr) "2010", "1995"
# $ Rated             (chr) "PG-13", "G"
# $ Released          (chr) "16 Jul 2010", "22 Nov 1995"
# $ Runtime           (chr) "148 min", "81 min"
# $ Genre             (chr) "Action, Mystery, Sci-Fi", "Animation, 
# ...
```

Interesting database btw... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'm really trying to learn R!

What does the Vectorize function do in this context?
How is such that I don't have to do Toy+Story (to fill in the url)?
Any other explanations of what's going on here would be very helpful!

Comment: It vectorizes your function, see `?Vectorize` or http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html and http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf. Why Toy+Story?

Comment: So I went to wikipedia and scraped all of Nic Cage's movies and then put to together in a value like the movies you did. I then did the df function but replaced moives with NicCage.Titles: df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vrottenrate(NicCage.Titles), function(x) as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

But got Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: Try `plyr::rbind.fill` instead of `rbind` (requires the plyr package to be installed).

Comment: Got it. Some of the name of the movie were spelled wrong when I grabbed the table ~ I wonder if I can solve that beforehand.